# How to implement a subset iterator for a class with N number of vectors in it

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

If I had a class that holds N number of equally sized `vectors`. How would I go about implementing a standard iterator template that would iterate between 1 and N number of the vectors together. I wrote a small example demonstrating the problem.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

//Since std::get<>() for types isn't in c++11, I use this meta-function to determine the index
//of a Type in a list of Types, starting from 0. ex: IndexOf<C,  A, B, C>::value = 2
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct IndexOf;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct IndexOf<T, T, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct IndexOf<T, U, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + IndexOf<T, Ts...>::value> {};

//Used to determine the slot we're interesting in.
using Handle = const std::size_t;

template<typename... Types>
class DataManager
{
    static constexpr std::size_t TypeCount = sizeof... (Types);
    using Flags = std::bitset<TypeCount>; //BitMask to determine if the handle has a certain piece of data initialized

    std::size_t count, capacity;
    std::tuple<std::vector<Types>..., std::vector<Flags>> vectors; //Tuple of vectors, holding the types and flags.
public:
    DataManager(std::size_t n) : count(0), capacity(n),
    vectors(std::make_tuple(std::vector<Types>(n)..., std::vector<Flags>(n)))
    {}

    template <typename Type, typename... Args>
    void add(Handle handle, Args&&... args) { //Initializes the type in the handle slot of the vector
        Flags& flags = std::get<TypeCount>(vectors)[handle];    //Flag the bit, notify that handle
        flags.set(IndexOf<Type, Types...>::value);              //has that piece of data initialized

        std::get<IndexOf<Type, Types...>::value>(vectors)[handle] = Type{ args... };
    }

    template <typename Type>
    Type& get(Handle handle) { //Returns the Type in handle slot of the vector
        return std::get<IndexOf<Type, Types...>::value>(vectors)[handle];
    }

    template <typename Type>
    bool has(Handle handle) { //Returns true if the Type is initialized, by checking the bitset
        Flags& flags = std::get<TypeCount>(vectors)[handle];
        return flags.test(IndexOf<Type, Types...>::value);
    }

    Handle push_back() {
        return count++;
    }
};
```

Which I currently use like this to access data:

```
//Simple Data
struct D0 { int x, y;    };
struct D1 { float  n, m; };
struct D2 { int x, y, z; };

int main()
{
    DataManager<D0, D1, D2> manager(100);
    Handle h0 = manager.push_back();

    std::cout << manager.has<D0>(h0) << std::endl;   //prints false, h0 doesn't have D0 initialized
    manager.add<D0>(h0, 75, 20);                     //initialize D0 for h0

    std::cout << manager.has<D0>(h0) << std::endl;   //prints ture, h0 is now initialzed
    std::cout << manager.get<D0>(h0).x << std::endl; //prints 75
}
```

How could I add iterator functionality to the DataManager class, that would only iterate over selected data like this?

```
 int main() 
 {
     ...
     for (D0 d1, D3 d3 : manager) {
         ... //Iterate over all D0s and D3s between 0 and count
     }
     //or 
     for(DataManager<D0>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it {
         ... //Iterate over just D0s between 0 and count - 10
     }
 }
```

Comment: What do you do with "missing" data that is not initialized (via flags?)  What do you do if the missing elements are not uniform over the range you are iterating over?  Have you seen boost zip iterators?  I am guessing you only need `for(:)` ranged-based loop iteration?

Comment: Oh sorry for not explaining the behavior for "missing" data. I'd want to skip over that slot. I want both a 'for(:)' based loop, and a iterator member for the full for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a range view type.  A range view has two iterators, a begin and an end, and exposes `.begin()` and `.end()`.  Returning a range view of iterators lets you do a `for(:)` loop without copying anything.

Next you'll want an iterator over the selected elements.  I can think of two approaches.

First, a zip iterator.  A zip iterator has a tuple of iterators, and it advances them in parallel.  When you dereference, it returns a `std::tie` of the dereference of each iterator.

Second option, a generator iterator.  A generator iterator has an index, and a function that maps from the index to some type.  `++` and `==` etc just advance/compare the index.  `*` returns the result of the function call.  In this case, you'd return a `tie` from the function.

I typically impelement a generator iterator by starting with an indexing iterator (that stores an index, and `*` returns a copy of it), then writing a transform iterator (that stores an iterator, forwards `==` and `++` and the like to it, stores a function `f`, and on `*` does `f(*it)` where `it` is the stored iterator).  A generator iterator is now just a `transform_iterator<F(index_iterator)>`.

---

These are both effectively limited to satisfying the axioms of an input iterator, due to the rules around `::reference` type and the like.  However, an input iterator is more than enough to do a `for(:)` loop; what more, a `for(:)` loop doesn't even need a legal iterator, as it is defined in terms of code not iterator semantics.

---

The generator/transform iterator is sufficient, and both are useful in other contexts, so I'd go with that approach.

You can choose to type-erase the transformation (into a `std::function< T(std::size_t) >`) if you want.

```
template<class T>
using any_generator_iterator = transform_iterator< std::function<T(std::size_t)>( indexing_iterator ) >;
```

Now to iterate over types A B and C we do:

```
template<class...Ts,
  class R=std::tuple<Ts&...>,
  class It=any_generator_iterator<R>
>
range_view< It >
iterate_over() {
  auto get = [this](std::size_t i)->R {
    return std::tie( this->get<Ts>()... );
  };
  return { {get, 0}, {{}, count} };
}
```

elsewhere:

```
for( auto i : foo.iterate_over<A,B,C>() ) {
  auto&& a = std::get<0>(i);
  auto&& b = std::get<1>(i);
  auto&& c = std::get<2>(i);
  // code
}
```

with a pile of library code on top of it.

Most, if not all, of this has been solved in `boost`.